# Querying a list in MongoDB without some fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The problem consists that i have this code at this moment:

```
resultList = list(self.collection.find({'jobId': {"$in": job_id_list}}))
```

This will return a list obviously.

I know that in Mongo, when you don't want some fields to be queried, you'd put:

```
'xml': 0, '_id': 0
```

where xml and _id are fields from the document being queried.

I would like to mix these 2 things, in which when I query a list, it will return the result without those 2 fields.

Not sure if explaining correctly.

I tried this:

```
list(self.collection.find({'jobId': {"$in": job_id_list, 'xml': 0, '_id': 0}}))
```

But it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you placed your exclusion parameters a bit too to deep. Please try following instead:

```
list(self.collection.find({'jobId': {"$in": job_id_list}}, {'xml': 0, '_id': 0}))
```

Comment: Excellent. Need to practice more then :) thank you!